# ZXing QR Code Generator app crashes with NPE

Tags: android, zxing

Before posting this here, I have already checked out other related posts on stackoverlfow but nothing seemed to really address a similar issue as mine.

This is the error I get:

```
06-29 21:02:38.274: E/AndroidRuntime(2261): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-29 21:02:38.274: E/AndroidRuntime(2261): Process: org.example.helloandroid, PID: 2261
06-29 21:02:38.274: E/AndroidRuntime(2261): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{org.example.helloandroid/org.example.helloandroid.QRGenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-29 21:02:38.274: E/AndroidRuntime(2261):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
06-29 21:02:38.274: E/AndroidRuntime(2261):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-29 21:02:38.274: E/AndroidRuntime(2261):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-29 21:02:38.274: E/AndroidRuntime(2261):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-29 21:02:38.274: E/AndroidRuntime(2261):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-29 21:02:38.274: E/AndroidRuntime(2261):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-29 21:02:38.274: E/AndroidRuntime(2261):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-29 21:02:38.274: E/AndroidRuntime(2261):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-29 21:02:38.274: E/AndroidRuntime(2261):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-29 21:02:38.274: E/AndroidRuntime(2261):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-29 21:02:38.274: E/AndroidRuntime(2261):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-29 21:02:38.274: E/AndroidRuntime(2261):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-29 21:02:38.274: E/AndroidRuntime(2261): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-29 21:02:38.274: E/AndroidRuntime(2261):     at org.example.helloandroid.QRGenActivity.onCreate(QRGenActivity.java:81)
06-29 21:02:38.274: E/AndroidRuntime(2261):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-29 21:02:38.274: E/AndroidRuntime(2261):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-29 21:02:38.274: E/AndroidRuntime(2261):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-29 21:02:38.274: E/AndroidRuntime(2261):     ... 11 more
```

This is my QRGenerator code that should generate the QR Code, but it throws a NPE.

```
public class QRGenActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String emailaddress = intent.getStringExtra("emailValue");
    String password = intent.getStringExtra("password");

    ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.qr);
    Log.d("EmailValue", emailaddress);
    Log.d("password", password);


    String qrInputText = emailaddress+"_"+password;
    Log.v("QR TAG", qrInputText);

    WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = manager.getDefaultDisplay();

    Point point = new Point();
    display.getSize(point);

    int width = point.x;
    int height = point.y;

    int smallerDimension = width < height ? width: height;
    smallerDimension*=3/4;

    com.google.zxing.Writer writer = new QRCodeWriter();
    String finalData = Uri.encode(qrInputText,"utf-8");

    try {
        BitMatrix bm = writer.encode(finalData, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 150, 150);
        Bitmap ImageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(150, 150, Config.ARGB_8888);

        for(int i=0;i<150;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<150;j++){
                ImageBitmap.setPixel(i, j, bm.get(i, j) ? Color.BLACK: Color.WHITE);
            }
        }

        if(ImageBitmap!=null){
Log.d("QRCreated", "QR Is created "+R.id.qr);

            view.setImageBitmap(ImageBitmap);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some error occurred in generating QRCode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (WriterException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    Handler handler = new Handler();
setContentView(R.layout.display_qr);

getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're putting

```
ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.qr);
```

before

```
setContentView(R.layout.display_qr);
```

This will not work, because `findViewById()` searches the view hierarchy for a view with the specified id, and you haven't added any views at that point. Hence, it will return null. This is likely to be the cause of the crash.

You should move the `setContentView()` call right after `super.onCreate()`.